# how to add a UITableView into UIAlertView in iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uialertview

did some googling around saw that subview is no longer supported in iOS 7.

Some ppl recommend creating custom view, but i am not sure how can i do that.

Here is my code, can anyone point me in the correct direction?

```
-(IBAction)click_select_fruit_type
{
select_dialog = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] retain];
[select_dialog setDelegate:self];
[select_dialog setTitle:@"Fruit Type"];
[select_dialog setMessage:@"\n\n\n\n"];
[select_dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

idType_table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 45, 245, 90)];
idType_table.delegate = self;
idType_table.dataSource = self;
[select_dialog addSubview:idType_table];

[idType_table reloadData];

[select_dialog show];
[select_dialog release];

}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can change *accessoryView* to any own *customContentView* in a standard alert view in iOS7

```
[alertView setValue:customContentView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

Note that you must call this before *[alertView show]*.

Simplest illustrating example:

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"subview" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[av setValue:v forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[av show];
```

[image]

Real *tableView* as the subview of *UIAlertView* example:

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution. Seems hacky but better than trying to find UIAlertview alternatives to be able to add subviews.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Apple deprecated ability to add any subviews to `UIAlertView` in iOS 7. Which I think is a good decision. A lot of people abused `UIAlertView`.

Creating a custom view is a good idea, but that's not what you wrote in your code. It seems like you are adding subviews to `UIAlertView` again.

See [Alert View UI guide here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView).

Comment: thanks from the link, i saw there is this thing called UIActionSheet

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIActionSheet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIActionSheet-SW1

Looks interesting

Comment: Yeah, that is one solution that people are using too. But if you subclass UIViewController to mimic UIAlertView, it's not a really bad idea either. Look around Github to see if anyone's done it yet.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to subclass `UIViewController` and use its `preferredContentSize` property to do some 'custom modal' mimicking UIAlertView layout