# Populating UITableView in UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uialertview

```
AlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
        message:nil
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
        otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)nil];
    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    [alert setValue:table forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

I'm using the above method to put a UITableView in my UIAlertView. Works fine but the cells are empty. I know how UITableView works, but I can't figure out how to populate the cells. `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: What object is serving as the table view's data source? Have you set that?

Comment: You need to define size of the table and implement all datasource and delegate methods as usually. I used to do the same. You can see screenshot in my answer for related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21067592/2066428)

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar! I had forgotten the data source since the way I was initializing the whole thing.

Comment: Can you share you cellForRowAtIndexPath and number of rows in section.