# How to create a UIAlertView with table view

Tags: objective-c, swift

I need to add a tableview inside a UIAlertView in Objective-C.

I tried to add a tableview as a subview of the alert view, but this is not working.

```
-(IBAction)ShowAlertWithTable
{
     UIAlertView *select_dialog ;
    select_dialog = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] retain];
    [select_dialog setDelegate:self];
    [select_dialog setTitle:@"Alphabets"];
    [select_dialog setMessage:@"\n\n\n\n"];
    [select_dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
  UITableView *  Type_table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 45, 245, 90)];
    Type_table.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   idType_table.delegate = self;
  idType_table.dataSource = self;
    [select_dialog addSubview:Type_table];
    [Type_table reloadData];
    [select_dialog show];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: Try to add it as accessory view.

Comment: Yes,i tried accessory view but it start from center@Ashish Kakkad

Comment: @UmaMaheshwaran Hi.. Did you manage to implement it? if so , can you please share the references.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use this library? It has all what you needs!

https://github.com/mindbrix/SBTableAlert

The above developer is using this 'Library' for AlertView

https://github.com/mindbrix/TSAlertView

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default alert isn't meant to take subviews. Although, you can write your own custom UIView that can meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late to answer the question. I want the same functionality in my application and after a little search I found my answer. 
You can use `UIAlertView`'s `setValue:<your UITableView> forKey:@"accessoryView"` property to add your `UITableView` in `UIAlertView`. You can create the `UITableview` programmatically to set value above. You can create and set any object like `UIView`, `UIImageView` etc. 
For more detail [Please refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067592/6325474)